# CSS: Progress bar, second background is appearing below bar instead of overlapping

Tags: html, css, progress-bar, ejs

I'm trying to create a Progress Bar. If user has completed 20%, a bar with my set colour is being created with the correct width. But for some reason, its appearing below my progress bar instead of overlapping and I have no idea why.

Bonus question: Any ideas why text is not aligned to center?

[image]

CSS:

```
.progress-bar {
    height: 20px;
    width: 126px;
    background: #BABABA;
    position: relative;
}

.progress-bar span {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.progress-bar div.bar {
    height: 20px;
    background: #336291;
    position: absolute;
}
```

EJS:

```
<td>
                        <div class="progress-bar">
                            <span><%= gamedata[i].progressPercentage %></span>
                            <div class="bar" style="width:<%= gamedata[i].progressPercentage %>;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the correct coordinates, so append the following lines:

```
.progress-bar div.bar {
    /* your code here */

    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

**Bonus answer:** your text is aligned in the center but your DOM element is not. What I suggest doing is giving automatic lateral margin and treating it as a block, like so:

```
.progress-bar span {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 15px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Didn't see bonus answer, will try later. I'll also have to make it readable now too, colour from second bar hides the text.

Answer (score 0):

try this code nothing big changes. Some small changes in css and HTML.

```
.progress-bar {
        height: 20px;
        width: 126px;
        background: #BABABA;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .progress-bar span {
        font-size: 1.1rem;
        font-weight: 600;
        line-height: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .progress-bar div.bar {
        height: 20px;
        background: #336291;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Hear is `html` code:

```
<td>
   <div class="progress-bar">
      <div class="bar" style="width:<%= gamedata[i].progressPercentage %>;">
          <center><%= gamedata[i].progressPercentage %></center>
      </div>
  </div>
</td>
```